# Can't manage object alignments selection with FabricJs 2

Tags: fabricjs, fabricjs2

I used to manage object alignments selection on FabricJS with `getActiveGroup` as below :

```
canvas.on("selection:created", function(e) {
    var activeObj = canvas.getActiveObject();
    console.log('e.target.type', e.target.type);
    if(activeObj.type === "group") {
        console.log("Group created");

        var groupWidth = e.target.getWidth();
        var groupHeight = e.target.getHeight();


        e.target.forEachObject(function(obj) {
            var itemWidth = obj.getBoundingRect().width;
            var itemHeight = obj.getBoundingRect().height;

            $('#objAlignLeft').click(function() {
                obj.set({
                    left: -(groupWidth / 2),
                    originX: 'left'
                });
                obj.setCoords();
                canvas.renderAll();
            });
            ...

    }
});
```

[more detailed here](https://jsfiddle.net/rekrah/xxrqbhph/)

But now that I use FabricJS 2 and that `getActiveObject()` has been removed, I don't know what to do. I read on the [doc](http://fabricjs.com/v2-breaking-changes-2) that we could use `getActiveObjects()`, but it does nothing.

Please how can I reproduce the action of [this code](https://jsfiddle.net/rekrah/xxrqbhph/) with FabricJS 2 (where `getActiveGroup` isn't supported anymore) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selections of more than one object have the type `activeSelection`. The `group` type is only used when you purposefully group multiple objects using `new fabric.Group([ obj1, obj2]`

When you create a multi-selection using the shift-key as opposed to drawing a selection box, you'll trigger the `selection:created` event only on the first object selected, while objects added to the selection will trigger the `selection:updated` event. By calling your alignment code from both the `selection:created` and `selection:updated` events you'll make sure that your code is executed every time a multi-selection is created.

Also, you can use `getScaledWidth()` and `getScaledHeight()` to get scaled dimensions, or just `.width` and `.height` if you just want the unscaled width/height values. Good luck!

```js
canvas.on({
  'selection:updated': function() {
    manageSelection();
  },
  'selection:created': function() {
    manageSelection();
  }
});

function manageSelection() {
  var activeObj = canvas.getActiveObject();
  console.log('activeObj.type', activeObj.type);
  if (activeObj.type === "activeSelection") {
    console.log("Group created");

    var groupWidth = activeObj.getScaledWidth();
    var groupHeight = activeObj.getScaledHeight();

    activeObj.forEachObject(function(obj) {
      var itemWidth = obj.getBoundingRect().width;
      var itemHeight = obj.getBoundingRect().height;
      console.log(itemWidth);

      $('#objAlignLeft').click(function() {
        obj.set({
          left: -(groupWidth / 2),
          originX: 'left'
        });
        obj.setCoords();
        canvas.renderAll();
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Please do you have a place where I could test your solution? Because I've tried your way but it doesn't work, `activeObj.type` never returns `group`. It returns `rect` or `text` (Based on the code of my jsfiddle)

Comment: Hi @kabrice, I've edited my answer. To check if your selection contains more than one object, use the type `activeSelection`, not `group`

Comment: Still doesn't work, It still returns `rect` or `text` as type. For your record, I used `FabricJS 2.3.3`.

Comment: I think I see the problem. I'm guessing you're using shift multi-select rather than the selection box to create your selection. By calling your alignment code from both the `selection:created` and the `selection:updated` events you can account for both types of selection methods. [see jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/melchiar/wxrjdLsy/)

Comment: Yes you were right. It works super great now :). Thank you very much